# Check File Extension in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, url, fetch, flv

How can I check the FileExtension of a URL which is sent from server in jsonResponce.

I want to pass a method if my URL has ".flv" in the end.

for example

http://derana.lk/apps/apple/tvderana/iframe_video.php?file=SriGauthamaSambuddha_35_19673.flv

Above link has ".flv" in the end.So i know that is a flv video. i want to know a method to check if my url has .flv in the end and if it has pass a method.

Comment: if its a string you can use `endsWith(suffix)` to check whetther it ends with a particular suffix http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, use FilenameUtils.getExtension from Apache Commons IO
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29

Here is an example of use:

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("YOUR STRING LINK HERE.flv");

if(ext.equalsIgnoreCase("flv"){
//IT IS FLV

 yourMethodToPlay();
}
```

or

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0) {
extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

Assuming that you're dealing with simple Windows-like file names, not something like archive.tar.gz.

Btw, for the case that a directory may have a '.', but the filename itself doesn't (like /path/to.a/file), you can do

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
int p = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf('/'), fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));

if (i > p) {
extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

However the Simplest way is to use FilenameUtils.getExtension Method

Comment: I'm getting links from a JSON. so there are so many. Some of them are flv and some of them are not. I want to play the videos that are only flv.how do i do that?

Comment: use filenameUtils, pase json and save the links into String. just pass that string to filenameutils.getextenstion it will return you the extension no matter it is flv, jpg or whatever, then check the condition and play the videos like the way you want

Comment: the code i mentioned has if condition you can simply put an else overthere play flvs and in else do your app logic with other extensions